# Display mask parameter on the mask icon

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a subsystem block that I would like to reuse significantly, with each instantiation differing only by a numeric parameter input via the block mask.  I would like to have the number of the parameter displayed as the icon of each block instantiation.

I have attempted to have it display via the icon drawing commands, but I am unsure as to the parameter value to be an input to the disp(), or fprintf() commands.  I've added a couple of pictures to detail my (simple) process so far.

[Via the mask overlay, a simple parameter is created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKj3I.png)

[I attempt to reference the parameter via the icon drawing commands.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hup6E.png)

Comment: Here is an example, both directly using a parameter (m or b) or using 'get_param' https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-mask-icon.html

Comment: @Daniel That is in the direction I want to head.  However, instead of using the parameters as values for drawing the icon, I just want to have the parameter value be displayed as the icon.

Comment: I assumed that was the part you already understood. Just use fprintf or disp. Did you try it? Does it print anything?

Comment: @Daniel I was not clear that about specifically the error I was running into.  I've attempted using the param in the disp() and fprintf() function, and it returns an error of an undefined function or variable.  I've updated the original question to include these details, as well as screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

1. You can add a get_param call to your display code `disp(get_param(gcb,'inputParam'))`
2. You can force the block to run initialization every time, thus ensuring the variable inputParam is accessible to the block without an explicit get_param call. To do this, go into the mask "Icon & Ports" tab and set "Run initialization" to "on" and then call `disp(inputParam)` like you already were.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Option 2 has also the advantage, that the variable is evaluated, which might be in the parameter field. If a variable is used instead of direct values in the parameter, option 1 just returns the variable name and not its value. Option 2 however, returns the content of the variable.